# How do I add ascx.cs file to the dnn7.(how to make zip of custom module) in dnn7

Tags: dotnetnuke-module

I am new to dotnetnuke. I do not know how to add ascx file to the dnn7 site. I have already zip file (module to install). and I have made few changes in cart.ascx.cs file that I want to add back to the dnn7 site.

I have **debug that cart.ascx file in vs studio and replaced that module's dll** in the existing zip file but it doesn't works out well. I have followed the instruction available by dnndev.me  but when I have installed the dotnetnuke project template and tried to add new project- C#-web to my solution it **asks me for getting the dnndev.me solution.**

**Please help me How can I add my module to the dnn7 site.**

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is not simple.  It seems like you have an existing DNN module zip file that includes source. You installed it in your DNN instance, and then made changes to one of the module controls.  Now you want to re-package and install again?  But it seems you also have trouble getting a module development environment setup?

I suggest going through a few hours of introductory training on setting up your DNN module development environment and understanding the module templates, build scripts, and packaging. I believe having a good foundation is time well spent. A few good tutorial that are specific to DNN7 I suggest are:

- [How to setup the Environment and Template to develop modules on
  DotNetNuke 7](http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/tabid/259/ArticleID/196/How-to-setup-the-Environment-and-Template-to-develop-modules-on-DotNetNuke-7-Part-1-3.aspx)
- [Introduction and Module Definition basics in DNN](http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/tabid/259/ArticleID/204/Introduction-and-Module-Definition-basics-in-DNN-Part-1-6.aspx)
- [Complete 101 Course - DNN Module Development](http://www.dotnetnuclear.com/articles/tabid/88/ID/9/categoryId/3/Southern-Fried-Training--DotNetNuke-7-Module-Programming-101.aspx)